# NSXMLDocument replacement on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, html, parsing

I have seen how an NSXMLDocument can parse an html document and provide easy methods for returning parts of the html structure.

Is there a similar method that can be used for the iPhone, as NSXMLDocument is not available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen TouchXML?

http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/wiki/TouchXML

Comment: How would I use something like that in my project?

Answer (score 0):

You might try this small document class which simply uses NSXMLParser:

https://github.com/nfarina/xmldocument

Answer (score -1):

Also see this blog post:

http://notes.bikemonkey.org/post/47351363/googles-nsxmldocument-replacement-for-iphone

Google has written a replacement for some NSXML stuff for iPhone.